# Pandas assign values from array in row to columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have following pandas

```
    | TEXT | FEATURE|
    | test | [0.2, 0.3, 0.4 .... n] |
    | test | [0.2, 0.3, 0.4 .... n] |
    |test2 | [0.2, 0.3, 0.4 .... n] |
    |test2 | [0.2, 0.3, 0.4 .... n] |
```

I need DataFrame to looks like

```
        | TEXT | FEATURE 1| FEATURE 2 | FEATURE 3 | FEATURE n |
        | test |  0.2,    |  0.3      |   0.4     |     n     |
        | test |  0.2,    |  0.3      |   0.4     |     n     |
        |test2 |  0.2,    |  0.3      |   0.4     |     n     |
        |test2 |  0.2,    |  0.3      |   0.4     |     n     |
```

FEATURE is np.array with `(300,)`

Answer (score 2):

here is one way to do it

drop the parenthesis and split on comma value, then concat with resulting column the TEXT column

```
df2=pd.concat([df['TEXT'],
           df['FEATURE'].str.replace(r'[\[\]]','', regex=True).str.split(',', expand=True).add_prefix('Feature_')], 
              axis=1)
df2
```

```
    TEXT    Feature_0   Feature_1   Feature_2   Feature_3
0   test    0.2     0.3     0.4     ....n
1   test    0.2     0.3     0.4     ....n
2   test2   0.2     0.3     0.4     ....n
3   test2   0.2     0.3     0.4     ....n
```

Comment: I like yours it adapts to the size of the given rows list

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
ft = pd.DataFrame(df['Feature'].to_list(), columns= [f'FEATURE {i}' for i in range(len(df['Feature'][0]))])

pd.concat([df.drop('Feature',axis=1),ft])
```

This shall give your wanted df